# Chromium automatic updating

Tags: updates, chromium, automatic

My chromium is automaticaly updating.please tell me a solution to disable that.I had disable all updates in software updater.

Comment: Prohibit updates is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `apt-mark`:**

You can use `apt-mark` to hold back the package so that it will not be updated automatically:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-mark hold chromium-browser
chromium-browser set on hold.

$ apt-mark showhold
chromium-browser
```

To cancel the hold status:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-mark unhold chromium-browser
Canceled hold on chromium-browser.
```

From `man apt-mark`:

> ```
>    hold
>        hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will 
>        prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or
>        removed.
> ```

**Using `dpkg` :**

Actually `apt-mark hold` is a wrapper around `dpkg --set-selections`, so you can use `dpkg --set-selections` directly:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --set-selections <<<'chromium-browser hold'
```